# How can I secure a "Send a Referral" email form?

Tags: php, forms, email, spam, spam-prevention

A client of mine has requested that I add a "send a referral" page to their website. This will contain a form that lets a user enter their name and email address as well as a friend's name and email address. When they submit the form, an email will be sent to their friend's email address containing a "check out this website" message.

**Can this type of referral form be made secure against spammers?**

I have already followed a lot of the advice in [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/82452/134458), including using `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` and `mb_encode_mimeheader` on the email addresses. I also have hidden "dummy" inputs in the form with specific values that will prevent form submission if a spammer overwrites them.

Comment: Try CAPTCHA On your form

Comment: @PhpDev I haven't, and I plan on doing so, but is that enough?

Comment: Captcha prevents most spam bots, but like any security measure the more it is used the more attempts will be made to "crack" it. So write your own custom one, less likely to be fixated for an attack although reCaptcha does a pretty fine job. Also look into the honey pot issue, its a manner to prevent bots to fill in certain input fields the correct way.

Comment: @Xorifelse Like I said, I have hidden inputs that, when modified, prevent the form from validating. From that I can tell, that is the honey pot solution.

Comment: Specifically check out [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/). This is the captcha that has you check a box. If it detects anything suspicious, it will make you do image recognition after checking the box.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to belong on security.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the hidden fields stop most of the spam. But if you want an extra measure, you can try [ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/). It's really easy to use and you should get rid of *most* of the spam.